# UIpopovercontroller shows at wrong position with Arrowdirectionup

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, uipopovercontroller

I am in a strange situation the problem is that i am showing a UIpopovercontroller which contains a datepicker and a done button. But when i show this with arrowdirectionup then it get by default Y direction from some where i tested it with x=0 and y=0 then x is working but the Y is still get value i dont know why it not working.

And if change the arrowdirection to down, right or left then it displayed at the right given position like 0,0.

```
datePopOver = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:datePopoverView];
[datePopOver setPopoverContentSize:CGSizeMake(307, 247)];
[datePopOver presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 307, 247) inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated:YES];
```

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5447948/uipopovercontroller-why-my-popover-doesnt-appears-where-i-want-to/5546679#5546679